# android x86 emulator not respecting vm.heapSize

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

The Android x86 ( API-10 ) emulator does not seem to respect the VM size specified through the AVD manager.  See below for config.ini created from AVD manager

```
hw.lcd.density=240
sdcard.size=64M
skin.name=WVGA800
skin.path=add-ons/addon-intel_atom_x86_system_image-intel_corporation-10/skins/WVGA800
hw.cpu.arch=x86
abi.type=x86
hw.keyboard=yes
vm.heapSize=96
hw.ramSize=256
image.sysdir.1=add-ons/addon-intel_atom_x86_system_image-intel_corporation-10/images/x86/
```

When I start up the app I print out what the maxmemory and a few details are using this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
Log.v("onCreate", "memoryClass:" + Integer.toString(memoryClass));
```

which gives me

```
10-12 17:07:53.817: VERBOSE/onCreate(222): maxMemory:25165824
10-12 17:07:53.827: VERBOSE/onCreate(222): memoryClass:24
```

using Ubuntu 12.04, SDK tools 20.0.3, platform tools 14.