# Memory allocated in empty Activity

Tags: java, android

**Background info** 
I'm building this app for months now and it's almost finished. But since a few days I'm seeing the memory going up with the Log like

```
D/dalvikvm(25624): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1782K, 17% free 22647K/27143K, paused 15ms+16ms, total 80ms
```

As you can see I've got a lot of memory allocated. 
So after searching/reading for a few days and using MAT to find my leaks, I've decided to strip down the application and build it up activity by activity in a new project to find out what the problem is.

**Question** 
So right now I have a new project and I'm opening just a single Activity.
I've added some images to the project, but they are not being used.
I've added a Function to the Activity so I can see the used memory in the log.

**Code**
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
        Log.d("HOME", "START");

        ShowMemoryStats("MAIN");
    }


    public void ShowMemoryStats(String activityName) {

        Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())
                / new Double((1048576));
        Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize()) / 1048576.0;
        Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()) / 1048576.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        Log.d("gettings", "debug. START ================================= "
                + activityName);
        Log.d("gettings",
                "debug.heap native: allocated " + df.format(allocated)
                        + "MB of " + df.format(available) + "MB ("
                        + df.format(free) + "MB free)");
        Log.d("gettings",
                "debug.memory: allocated: "
                        + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime()
                                .totalMemory() / 1048576))
                        + "MB of "
                        + df.format(new Double(
                                Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1048576))
                        + "MB ("
                        + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime()
                                .freeMemory() / 1048576)) + "MB free)");

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
        Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
        Log.v("onCreate", "memoryClass:" + Integer.toString(memoryClass));

        Log.d("gettings", "debug. END ================================= "
                + activityName);
    }
```

**Result** 
    debug. START ================================= MAIN
    debug.heap native: allocated 2,41MB of 2,59MB (0,18MB free)
    debug.memory: allocated: 12,00MB of 64,00MB (0,00MB free)
    maxMemory:67108864
    memoryClass:64
    debug. END ================================= MAIN

So right now I would just like to know what is causing this memory-usage.
Is this some kind of default memory that every app gets on startup?

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE [30-12-2012]** 
Still working on this problem, but sometimes I'm thinking it's a non-issue. The reason is that when I use the AVD (Heapsize: 24MB) I see a total different result:
[image]

in comparison to when I debug the app on my phone (Galaxy S3):
[image]

Comment: Have you already checked [googles io on memory management](http://youtu.be/_CruQY55HOk?t=19m37s), the part about the app rotating and keeping ref to activities?

Comment: Yup, all my activities have the property android:screenOrientation="portrait". But the wierd part is the big difference in heap dump between the AVD and using it on the phone..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868366/android-x86-emulator-not-respecting-vm-heapsize

Answer (score 0):

If you say you are using MAT, you should be able to search for leaks based on threads that are considered suspicious.

Also, if you want to get specific data from a specific suspicious object, try this:
http://www.javamex.com/classmexer

*I'm not sure if the Android API supports this kind of mechanism.

Comment: Tnx! When I use MAT I can see that there is a Bitmap object > 9MB. I  also see that some activities have multiple instances. So I know there is problem there. But I can not figure out where the 9 MB comes from. Right now I just want to figure out why there is more then 2MB allocated while I only started an empty activity.